# Validation control issue

Tags: asp.net, validation, multiview

I have a multiview that simulates a menu with different kind of options.

Each view within the multiview control holds a bunch of controls (listbox, label, etc..)
Everything worked just fine, until i wanted to implement Validation control(s).

For example when i click on my menu viewA gets displayed with its controls.
There i wish to implement a RequiredFieldValidator.

But the problem is, if i click on a other menu option (which is in fact a other view in my multiview) then it gives the error message 'Please enter a message" which is the errorMessage of the first RequiredFieldValidator of the first menu option (first view).

All my controls are named with a unique name, so there is no mixup amongst the ControlToValidate=""

Offcourse this is not suitable, cause those menu choices are indepentant.
And its not the intention i have to fill in everything, cause its a menu afterall, and not a form where i have to enter everything at once.

How can i have a RequiredFieldValidator on my views that do not take each other in account?

Some code on how my active view is handled

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        View activeView = (View)this.mvMultiview.FindControl(this.getViewFromRequest());
        if (!(activeView == null))
        {
            this.mvMultiview.SetActiveView(activeView);
        }
     }
 }
```

Thanks.